# MySQL, Java and UTF8

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have a database with `MEDIUMBLOB` fields in tables with `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` on each table.

I connect to the database with `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8&character_set_client=UTF8&character_set_database=UTF8&character_set_results=UTF8&character_set_server=UTF8&character_set_system=UTF8` on the URL.

(I have tried with just `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8` with the same results.)

When I look at values in the database using `mysql` from the command-line, I can see non-ASCII characters just fine.

But when I read in strings from the database using `executeQuery()` `getString()` I get gibberish.  How can I read in the values correctly?

I am using log4j to show the strings I am writing to the database, and those I read back, and those I write show fine.

Comment: How are you then *displaying* those strings? If it's via a web application or something like that, it could be that you're getting the right data back from the database, but then something's going wrong when it needs to be encoded to be sent to the browser.

Comment: (I'm assuming that by "gibberish" you mean all kinds of odd characters where you expected the non-ASCII characters, aka [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). If you're seeing just question marks, that's a different matter.)

Comment: I would be happy if it ever be solved, are you using console for displaying? What the device is displaying your chars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a BLOB, not a string. So you want `getBytes` and decode it manually.

```
 new String( bytes, "UTF-8"); //Subsitute "UTF-8" with whatever encoding the blob is in
```

If you want more transparent support, defined a mediumtext column with UTF-8. Then all that configuration will become effective and you get proper strings automatically with getString.

Comment: Yup, was about to add something similar as a comment - I hadn't noticed the field type to start with. (I wish drivers would actually *fail* when you tried to ask for a value using the wrong type, instead of giving you a quite-possibly-wrong conversion.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I wish that too, but that's *definitely* not how MySQL does things. They always *try to give you something*. Even if chances are that that something is wrong.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: True. My experience is that it's the case with many other databases (or at least their .NET and Java drivers) too.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` part will only work if whatever's *storing* the data uses UTF-8. It's possible that actually the original code would be fine, but the data is being stored using a different encoding (in the original "storing" client)...

Comment: @JonSkeet true, now that I read the post again, nowhere is it mentioned that the blob binaries are in fact in UTF-8.

Comment: The blob binaries were written using `setString()`.

Comment: @Will: then why do you use a `MEDIUMBLOB`? It should be a `MEDIUMTEXT` (a `CLOB`).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I didn't make the schema.